# Java 8 Stream groupingBy with custom logic

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Records`. Which has two fields: `LocalDateTime instant` and a `Double data`.

I want to groupBy all the records by Hour and create a `Map<Integer, Double>`. Where the keys (Integer) are hours and values(Double) are last Data of that hour - first Data of that hour.

What I have done so far is following:

```
Function<Record, Integer> keyFunc = rec->rec.getInstant().getHour();
Map<Integer, List<Record>> valueMap = records.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyFunc));
```

I want the value map to hold `Double` instead of `List<Records>`.

For Example: List records can be following:

```
Instant            Data
01:01:24           23.7
01:02:34           24.2
01:05:23           30.2
...
01:59:27           50.2
02:03:23           54.4
02:04:23           56.3
...
02:58:23           70.3
...
```

etc

Resulting map should be:

```
Key       Value
1          26.5 (50.2-23.7)
2          15.9 (70.3-54.4)
...
```

Comment: can you explain this with an example `values(Double) are last Data of that hour - first Data of that hour.`?

Comment: Please edit the question with your exact expectation as stated in the [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967280/java-8-stream-groupingby-with-custom-logic/53967306#comment94772377_53967306).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mostly looking for [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) within the `groupingBy`.

```
Map<Integer, List<Double>> valueMap = records.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyFunc, 
                Collectors.mapping(Record::getData, Collectors.toList())));
```

This would group `Record`s by their `instant`'s hour and corresponding data for such records into a `List` as values of the map. Based on comments further

> I want to subtract the first data from the last data
>
> Yes the list will be sorted list based on instant

you can use the grouped map to get the desired output as:

```
Map<Integer, Double> output = new HashMap<>();
valueMap.forEach((k, v) -> output.put(k, v.get(v.size() - 1) - v.get(0)));
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) with [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) further as:

```
Map<Integer, Double> valueMap = records.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyFunc,
                Collectors.mapping(Record::getData, 
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.toList(), recs -> recs.get(recs.size() - 1) - recs.get(0)))));
```

Comment: Can the resulting map be Map<Integer,Double>? The value of that map would be last data of that hour - first data of that hour against hour as the key.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *last data of that hour*? for e.g. every hour now is a unique key, what would be the "last data" in the list above?

Comment: Suppose there are 10 records of a particular hour say 20th hour. Because, instant field is a timestamp. The first being 20:01:36 last being 20:59:20 there are 8 other records in between. I want to substract the first data from the last data.

Comment: @Deb 1. If you group by an hour, why are you worried to subtract minutes/seconds based data? 2. Is it possible then for you to have a sorted list based on instant?

Comment: Yes the list will be sorted list based on instant and resulting Map would be something like:  1=>23.2 ,  2=>30.4,   3=> 89.0..etc

Comment: @Deb Updated, mostly that's what you might be looking for.

Comment: @nullpointer Are you sure you don't need to sort `recs` before computing the difference?

Comment: @ernest_k Well, I relied on the comment from OP, which states that the records are sorted based on the instant.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collectingAndThen` as a downstream collector to `groupingBy`, and use the two extreme values of each group to compute the difference:

```
Map<Integer, Double> result = records.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(rec -> rec.getInstant().getHour(),

        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(), 
                list -> {
                    //please handle the case of 1 entry only
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getInstant));

                    return list.get(list.size() - 1).getData() 
                           - list.get(0).getData();
                })));
```

`Collectors.groupingBy(rec -> rec.getInstant().getHour()` will group entries by hour. As used here, `Collectors.collectingAndThen` will take hourly entries as lists, sort every such list by the `instant` field then find the difference between the two extreme elements.

Comment: But I need lastRecord.getData() - firstRecord.getData() as value

Comment: @Deb I see. I was just commenting about that. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment that the list would be sorted on timestamp, the following would work
:

```
    Map<Integer, Double> valueMap = records.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rec -> rec.getInstant().getHour(),
                    Collectors.mapping(Record::getData,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),recs -> recs.get(recs.size()-1) - recs.get(0)))));
```